# How to auto increment build version in Xcode only if the user name is XXX?

Tags: xcode, bash, shell

How to auto increment build version in Xcode only if the user name is XXX?

I tried:

```
 #!/bin/bash
    if [$USER == "XXX"];then
    buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
     buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
    /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
   fi
```

But no success.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found it:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $ALTERNATE_OWNER == "XXX" ]; then
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "$INFOPLIST_FILE")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "$INFOPLIST_FILE"
fi
```